# Google Pagespeed "Third-Party Usage" issue

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have optimized my website in every possible way, but when I am testing performance in google [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fzubizi.com%2Fgst-billing-software-for-retail-shop.html&tab=mobile) tool it shows "Third-Party Usage 4 Third-Parties Found"

I have used **defer / async** loading external scripts and used **preconnect** also but this error is still showing.

[image]

What should I do???

Here are full details of the performance check:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fzubizi.com%2Fgst-billing-software-for-retail-shop.html&tab=mobile

Comment: "Limit the number of redundant third-party providers". Are any of those dependencies redundant in your case? If not then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv it is just google analytics and AdWords configs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity this is not an error message - anything under the 'diagnostics' section is for your information to help you diagnose any outstanding performance issues.

It does NOT affect your score directly.

The only way to avoid this is to bundle the 4 items together into a single file and include them as a script served from your own server.

I do this with Google Analytics (so I can avoid Sub Resource Integrity errors in Mozilla Observatory) by downloading the file each night and caching it locally.

I would not worry about it at all, your performance problems come from the other 460kb of JS you have in your concated.js file so if you want to improve performance, start by looking there to remove as many libraries as you can.

Also the CSS you have inlined to minimise critical request chains is gigantic, try optimising that to only include 'above the fold' CSS as that is all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)  Is there any ways to improve performance with `Bootstrap, jQuery`? I used `gulp-purgecss` to remove unwanted styles from **CSS**. It works well but there are some issues that I couldn't resolve!

Comment: The places I would start are looking at making your fonts none blocking. Then if I wanted to hit 100% on page speed I would re-write the JS from the ground up (yes extreme I know) rather than using massive libraries such as jQuery and Bootstrap. I use a library called ki.js and ki-extend.js instead of jQuery BUT you have to work around things with it and is not for the faint of heart. However the results are worth it (see https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fklu.io)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - Thanks for sharing this details. But removing the GTM script from my website improved the Lighthouse/PSI mobile scores by 5 points. 
I would try the bundling approach you recommended, but how can we make sure that the latest Google script gets loaded in our application. Seems like some extra steps to take care of this.

Comment: @VimalMaheedharan in order to do this you simply query the GTM CDN once a day, download the script to your server and change your script include to point to your server instead of the CDN. It doesn't matter if they are a day out of date. Obviously you need to do some cache busting at your side to ensure the version you downloaded last night is served. However this technique is for combining external scripts. If one particular script (GTM) is slowing things down you may want to defer loading the script using a `setTimeout` a couple of seconds after all the critical stuff has loaded.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - Thanks for your inputs! Will try it out.